# How to disable scrollview for list view and apply scrollview for entire activity containing list views and other textviews?

Tags: android

I have an xml file containing different buttons, textviews, list views.Listview has default scrollview which is scrolling for certain part in an activity.But how to display all the "n" cells in list view by disabling scroll view and apply scroll view for entire page containing listviews,textviews,Buttons etc
xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#edecf2"
    tools:context="com.bodaty.samyata.samyata09.orders.openorderdetails">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
            tools:ignore="ScrollViewSize">

   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                tools:targetApi="n">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:text="@string/store_pricen"
                            android:textAlignment="textStart"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            tools:targetApi="n" />



                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/stprice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"                                android:fontFamily="@font/montserratsemibold"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:lines="1"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/price"
                            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            tools:targetApi="n" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:text="@string/sales_tax"
                            android:textAlignment="textStart"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            tools:targetApi="n" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:divider="@null"
                />


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                tools:targetApi="n">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_storeicon"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView12"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/store_location"
                            android:textAlignment="textStart"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratsemibold"
                            tools:targetApi="n"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:gravity="start" />

                    </LinearLayout>




                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/st1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                        tools:targetApi="n"
                        android:gravity="start" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/st2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                        tools:targetApi="n"
                        android:gravity="start" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/st3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                        tools:targetApi="n"
                        android:gravity="start" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:background="#808080">

                    </View>


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:id="@+id/directions">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ic1"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/placeholder"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            />


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/way_to_the_storen"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
                            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_forearr"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/phide"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                tools:targetApi="n">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_locationorders"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/dl"
                            android:textAlignment="textStart"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/questrial"
                            tools:targetApi="n"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:gravity="start" />

                    </LinearLayout>




                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dl1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/questrial"
                        tools:targetApi="n"
                        android:gravity="start" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dl2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/questrial"
                        tools:targetApi="n"
                        android:gravity="start" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dl3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/questrial"
                        tools:targetApi="n"
                        android:gravity="start" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                tools:targetApi="n">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        >
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/truck"/>



                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/deliverymethod"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratsemibold"
                            tools:targetApi="n"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="@string/personal_shopper"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                            android:id="@+id/delivery"
                            tools:ignore="InefficientWeight"

                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                            tools:targetApi="n"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:id="@id/pslayout">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/label"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="Personal Shopper Details"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                            tools:targetApi="n"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,InefficientWeight" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:id="@+id/top"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            >
   <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/dp"
                                android:layout_width="138dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/usn"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/pstrack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:hint="Track your PersonalShopper"
                                android:textSize="17sp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/questrial"
                                tools:targetApi="n"
                                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,InefficientWeight" />
                        </LinearLayout>



                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                                android:text="@string/id1"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/uid"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
                                android:text="@string/random"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                tools:targetApi="n" />

                        </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                                    android:text="@string/delivery_status"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"
                                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/status"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
                                    android:text="@string/product_picked_up"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"
                                    android:textSize="14sp"
                                    tools:ignore="InefficientWeight"
                                    tools:targetApi="n" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: shar your XML code here.

Comment: I have shared sir @QadirHussain

Comment: set the height of linear layout after scrollview wrap_content

Answer (score 1):

set the height of listview to wrap_content